# Holding a key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, serial-port

I'm writing a simple python code to receive a serial string defining a joystick's position, separate X and Y and do keyboard commands accordingly.

In my code I'm attempting to that, while the user holds the joystick to the right, the -> stays pressed and it's release afterwards. To do this I'm using the [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) library. What happens however is that the right key stays pressed indefinately and the character (Megaman inside an emulator) just runs towads it's death. Could anyone help me figure out why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
import serial
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard


control = PyKeyboard()
try:
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on /dev/ACMDUSB0"
while True:
    xy = arduino.readline()
    if xy is "":
        print ("NULL")
    else:
        x, y = xy.split("_")
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        while(x > 700):
                control.press_key(control.right_key)
        control.release_key(control.right_key)
        print ("X = {0}\nY = {1}".format(x, y))
```

Comment: When is `x` supposed to drop to or below 700?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the joystick ranges from 0 to 1023, so it stays stable at ~511/~512 when untouched. It goes over 700 when the user pushes it to the right, and when release 'x' goes back to 511.

Comment: Okay, but *when does `x` change*?

Comment: I'm confused whereas to what "when" means. IRL it changes when the joystick is tilted to the left or right. In the code I receive X and Y on the first line inside the `while True`, and I split it after the `else` . So, technically it would change on the next loop of while.

Comment: Yes, but you're stuck in the inner `while` loop, waiting for something that will never happen.

Comment: Ha! Oh my, that's silly! Thanks a bunch @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams! But another problem arises though, how to actually perform this correctly. would making a function like `def getxy():
    xy = arduino.readline()
    x, y = xy.split("_")
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    return x, y` and calling it inside the while help?

Comment: The problem with making it a function is that if you delay calling the function for any reason then you will get old values and hence high latency. Just compare the latest value and hold or release as needed. Keep the current state in another variable to eliminate unneeded state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams in the comments section the error was due to me not rechecking which controls were pressed at the end of the while loop, thus making it run indefinately.